# Separate log files for separate instances of same class

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Client and Server class. There is one Client instance running and eight Server instances running at the same time in the same JVM.

I now wish to (programatically or through properties file) setup log4j so that I'd have one log file per class instance. For the example above I'd like to have 9 separate log files.

Comment: Why do you run them in the same VM?

Comment: You're probably not going to like this, but it seems you are using logging for debugging purposes, which is an antipattern. Better write automated tests.

Comment: I'm currently trying to pinpoint the location where the problem occurs, before I actually go debugging. The funny thing is that I'm actually debugging a unit test...
@ChristianSchlichtherle What I'm doing feels wrong. Can you perchance point me to some resource on this antipattern?

Comment: Well, it was a general comment - no offense intended. But rather than adding logging statements, I would write a unit test which tests for multithreading. There are plenty of resources on the web about writing unit tests, so you sure find some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same Logger for all the instances (v.g., `private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class)`, all logs will follow the same process.

You should define the logger as an instance attribute and setup a different behavior for each one in the log4j.properties, v.g.

```
private final Logger log;

public MyClass(String instanceID) {
  this.log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.toString() + "_" + instanceID);
}
```